# Json exception is thrown while getting user profile image from facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following problem: I need to get user avatar from fb. Here's the way how I do it:

```
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            accessToken,
            "/"+USER_ID+"/picture",
            response -> {
                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
                try {
                    JSONObject data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                    String url = data.getString("url");
                    Glide.with(getContext()).load(Uri.parse(url)).into(avatar);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

    request.executeAsync();
```

When I run the app I catch a JSONException:

> W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:612)
>           at com.mikhailovskii.trakttv.ui.profile.ProfileFragment.lambda$onCreateView$1$ProfileFragment(ProfileFragment.java:60)
>           at com.mikhailovskii.trakttv.ui.profile.-$$Lambda$ProfileFragment$opSQfyBaYXGAS004ZXJX6UymkGE.onCompleted(Unknown
>   Source:4)
>           at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1395)

Here's the JSON which I should get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "height": 50,
    "is_silhouette": true,
    "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50a/p50x50/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?_nc_cat=1&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=60206c93f484956b6672f23d36e5db8c&oe=5D54D1E8",
    "width": 50
  }
}
```

As I read, there's no need to get any permissions for getting image. The code of the error I get is 200 and it means that `Permissions error`. So, why this problem happens?

Comment: What JSON did you get? And if you didn't get JSON. What response did you get? The full response? Facebook will tell you want the error is.

Comment: @WizKid, I have this: `{"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":"����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000��\u0000�Photoshop"}` or you meant not this?